# How does Dr Madeleine Swann know that something has happened with her father?

Tags: dialogue, james-bond, spectre

In *Spectre*, Bond visits Dr. Madeleine Swann for his psychological assessment. From which of his answers does Swann learn that something has happened with her father?

How does she come to the conclusion that bond knows her father from Bond's cryptic talk?

She asks bond about his profession in the below dialogue

> Dr Swann: What is your occupation?
> Bond: Well, that's not the sort of thing
> that looks good on a form.
> Dr Swann: And why is that?
> Bond: I kill people. Small world?

and later she directly asks bond about her father referring her father as "he", at which point both of them seem to be sure about whom they are talking.

> Dr Swann: Where is he?
> Bond: Your father's dead.

Comment: From the script I can see ... Bond straight out tells her that her father is dead and that he knows because he was there.  I don't answer properly because I can't remember the scene exactly and the script may be unreliable.  Are you sure she comes to the conclusion from "cryptic talk"?

Comment: @iandotkelly I am sure that it's cryptic talk that leads her to ask about her father. It could be that her father's profession is also killer but as said  in 1st answer by Tetsujin its the words "its small world .. unhh?"

Comment: If someone tells you he kills people for a living, and then tells you that your father is dead, what conclusion are *you* going to come to?

Answer (score 6):

As in comments, there really is nothing cryptic about it. It's plainly stated.

[Transcribed by ear]

> Swann: Where is he?
> Bond:  Your father's dead. Two days ago.
> Swann:  How do you know?
> Bond:  Because I was there.
> Swann:  Did you kill him?
> Bond:  I didn't have to. He did it himself.
> Swann:  And you came all the way, just to tell me this? That my father's dead.
> Bond:  I came to tell you that your life is in danger and I need your help.

…then on we go with the plot.

The only potentially cryptic part is from the last question on the form [abridged]

> Swann: Occupation?
> Bond: I kill people. Small world, huh?

Without context, 'small world' could be potentially confusing, (and, in fact, as I haven't seen the whole movie in a long time, I don't know precisely to what he is referring).